# Create war artifact automatically using Glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, artifacts

In `Intellij Idea` (as well as in any other popular IDE) it is possible to build and create artifact from sources (*.java files, web.xml, etc.). Then, it is possible to make *.war archive and deploy application into Glassfish application server.

Everytime, I have to manually make all these steps and, finally, deploy war file using administrator's console `localhost:4848` or the folder `autodeploy`.

Is there is a way to do this automatically (using command-line script or anything else)?

What should be done programmatically:

1. Compile `*.java` sources
2. Build a `*.war` artifact
3. Deploy into `glassfish`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems that I solved the problem. I did not use any libraries and made everything from skratch using terminal commands for compilation, building war and copying war into autodeploy folder.